# sortable list in list.js doesn't seem to be working

Tags: listjs

I copied the example from http://listjs.com/examples/table/ of a sortable table, but it's not working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

I have these links in my `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/material-design-lite/material.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

html:

```
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>
  <table>
    <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonny Stromberg</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Jonas Arnklint</td>
        <td class="born">1985</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Martina Elm</td>
        <td class="born">1986</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</td>
        <td class="born">1983</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
<script src="//listjs.com/assets/javascripts/list.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/includes/material-design-lite/material.min.js"></script>
```

js:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var options = {
      valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
    };

    var userList = new List('users', options);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute URL when linking list.js:

```
<script src="http://www.listjs.com/assets/javascripts/list.min.js"></script>
```